# Haskell: Determine type of parameter in data type

Tags: haskell, ghc

Let's say I define a data type as follows:

```
data Type = MyInt |
            MyBool |
            MyFun Type Type
```

and I have a variable `type_a = MyFun MyInt MyBool`

and I have another variable `type_b = MyInt`

How would I check if type_b = the first parameter in type_a (MyInt)?

Comment: You can use pattern matching, so: `f (Type x _) = x` and `type_b = f type_a`.

Comment: `deriving Eq` also allows you to use `==` after you extract the domain type using pattern matching as Willem suggested. E.g. `case type_a of Type x _ -> x == type_b ; _ -> False` will evaluate to `True` if `type_b` is the domain of `type_a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can derive `Eq` then use pattern matching to destructure `MyFun` and compare the first argument to `type_b`:

```hs
data Type = MyInt | MyBool | MyFun Type Type deriving Eq

type_a = MyFun MyInt MyBool
type_b = MyInt

firstArgEquals :: Type -> Type -> Bool
firstArgEquals (MyFun a _) b = a == b
firstArgEquals _ _ = False

firstArgEquals type_a type_b -- returns True
```

Comment: ...and, not to put too fine a point on it, but the `Eq` instance that's derived doesn't require compiler magic to implement. It's just a shorthand. You could write it out at length by hand yourself, and it would use the exact same mechanism: pattern matching.